# Where did the protagonist get the 200 years he gambled in In Time?

Tags: in-time

I'm watching *In Time*, a movie where time is a currency.

The main character had 18 hours and was given a gift of 116 years by a wealthy man who was ready to die. The man told him only

> Don't waste my time.

Despite this the protagonist immediately proceeded to spend about 10 - 15 years of time in travel fees and hotels, then bet 50 years at a casino. A person he was playing cards against raised him by 200 years. He called the bet.

Where did he get the 200 years?

Comment: never watched the movie so wont make this an answer however in most casinos you cant just buy the pot outright by betting more than someone has so in the above example the player who bet 200 would only throw something like 101 years in the pot to match the 101 years the main character actually had and if there were other players in the hand who had 200 years then 101 of their years would go into the main pot while 99 of them would go into a side pot that the main character would not be playing for

Comment: @revenant Gambling is *so* complicated. I suspected it might be something like that, but I do know that he had 100 years or less, then he scanned his wrist to deposit 50 of the 100, then after the (only) other gambler raised to 200 he said "call" and scanned his wrist again to pay more time.

Comment: Could someone please tell me why they downvoted this? It appears to be serial voting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, watching the scene I think we are to believe that the protagonist has been sitting at the table for a while and has increased his stake since he would have had to put over the 250 years we see him bet into the pot for it to reach the 1100 years.

I think they either cut scenes or never filmed them.

Answer (score 3):

The implication from the film's original script is that Will (and the other players) have been playing for several hours. The hand that we see played is quite literally the final hand of the evening, strongly implying that at the point that we return to the action Will has *already* doubled his time, presumably by winning several smaller hands.

Note that the script shows a *dissolve* (usually intended to show the passage of time) rather than a cut.

> Will looks to the poker tables
>
> **WILL:** *What's the limit?*
>
> **HOST:** *There is none.*
>
> **DISSOLVE**
>
> INT. CASINO - POKER TABLE. NIGHT.
>
> Close on a TIMEPIECE in the center of the poker table flashes with SIX
>   HUNDRED YEARS and change.

and the thought process of the other players

> Sylvia stares at Will, astonished at the risk he just took - finally
>   breaks her stare as **Philippe rises from the table. The other players
>   follow suit - they have also had enough.**
>
> **PHILIPPE:** *I think you've taken enough years off my life **for one evening*** (extending his hand) *Philippe Weil.*
>
> **WILL:** *Will Salas.*